# Изменение результата в зависимости от параметра Option и параметра Input в Select

Tags: javascript

Окажите содействие, пожалуйста - мне необходимо, чтобы в зависимости от выбранного в `Select` `Option` пересчитывался результат "*Стоимость Вашего заказа -* ".

Если меняю цифры в `.quantit` - все ок, пересчитывает, а если меняю параметры `Select` - то разницы нет. Плюс эта форма еще будет сидеть в модальном окне.

```
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
  <form role="form">
  <select class="form-control akciya">
 <option></option>
 <option value="Option_1">Option_1</option>
 <option value="Option_2">Optoin_2</option>
</select>

 <div class="form-group">
  <label for="quantity">Количество бутылей</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control quantity" id="quantity" placeholder="Пароль">
 </div>
<p>Стоимость Вашего заказа <span class="sum_rezult"></span></p>
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">отправить</button>
</form>
  </div>
   </div>
</div>
  <script>
  jQuery(".quantity").keyup(function () {



      var value = jQuery(this).val();
        if(parseInt(value) <2) {
            value = +2;
        }

        else value = +value;
        var option_select = $("select.akciya").val();
    if (option_select == "Option_1"){
    var k = +(value-1);
    }
    else k = +value;
  var sum_rezult = +40*k + " грн.";


      jQuery(".sum_rezult").text(sum_rezult);
        }).keyup();
</script>
```

Comment: вообще-то, всё работает https://jsfiddle.net/mts7nfmx/ правильно -неправильно, другой вопрос. но непонятно, что вы хотите

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я правильно понял, что вы меняете значение выпадающего списка и ничего не происходит?
Если так, то вы не подписаны на это событие. Ваше событие работает только на `keyup` вашего инпута.
Вам необходимо еще подписаться на

```
$(".akciya").change(  CalculateMyPrice );
```

Тут я вынес вычисления цены в отдельную функцию `CalculateMyPrice`

Comment: и еще в этом операторе `if (option_select = "Option_1"){` присваивание на сравнение надо поменять

Comment: @splash58 О, я и не заметил. Было бы неплохо конечно :)

Comment: А еще пользователь может не с клавиатуры ввести значение в текстовый инпут, а правой кнопкой мыши -> Вставить. Так что я Вам рекомендую еще `keyup` заменить на `jQuery(".quantity").on("input  change", function () { и так далее`. `change` вторым параметром для поддержки старых браузеров. Если не требуется, можно(и нужно) его опустить.

Comment: спасибо большое, сейчас учтя все ваши советы попробую исправить

Comment: туплю, сорри, сдела как Вы подсказали, но не выходит https://jsfiddle.net/mts7nfmx/12/ что не так ? я так понял с подпиской на второе событие лажа? только как связать их не могу понять как. Помогите. плз.

Comment: решение найдено http://jsbin.com/nuborinoqe/edit?html,js,console,output